# Can I cut a water sediment filter in half and how?

Tags: filter, water-filtration

I acquired some 20" sediment filters (see image) that are twice the height of the filter housing that I have.

In an unrelated side project I cut a small part off the end of one of these filters. I used a regular wood saw and discovered that the cut part disintegrates fairly quickly.

Questions:

- Is it okay to cut one of these in half to use inside a 10" filter housing?
- How do I cut this so that it has a clean edge/surface on the cut part? (Obviously assumes that answer is "yes" to previous question.)

[image: sediment filter]

Comment: Usually a filter cartridge is a filter and casing bonded together, not two separate parts.  Once it cut/holed/taken apart it does not work well, and will probably fall apart soon after if used.

Comment: Would it be more cost effective to get another filter housing that supports the filter element you have. You will get twice the life maybe more with the 20". I am guessing if they are available as a replacement part but considering the replacement cartridge it should be.

Comment: You don't show the whole filter - if it's the "plain" tubular type, probably fine to cut with a handsaw. Or better yet, just buy a 20" filter housing, since you have a supply of 20" filters now...

Comment: As another alternative, get a 20" filter holder and _add_ it to your system instead of replacing the 10" one. That way, whether you acquire 10" or 20" filters in the future, they'll pop right in to the appropriate holder. Leaving the cover on the unused one will simply allow it to fill with water that flows right through instead of being filtered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it okay to cut one of these in half to use inside a 10" filter housing?

No clue.

> How do I cut this so that it has a clean edge/surface on the cut part?

What is "wood saw"? If you're talking about a circular saw with a wood blade then I am not surprised that things disintegrated.

Your best bet would be a 10" or larger miter saw with a high tooth count blade; not the crap demo blade that most units are sold with.

Better yet would probably be a cutoff wheel.

Regardless, make sure to go nice and slow so that things have a chance to be microscopically shaved instead of butchered.

[image]